# Google search results say "no information is available for this page" instead of meta description for page not blocked by robots.txt

Tags: seo, meta-description, magento

[image]

I cant see Meta Description for my page. I know its added on the backend. Its not blocked by robots.txt

Answer (score 2):

That page is blocked by robots.txt.  The URL on your site is

```
/catalogsearch/result/index/?f=shop+by+brand+little+darling+nb+accessories&q=shop+by+brand+little+darling
```

And your robots.txt contains the rule:

```
Disallow: /*?
```

That blocks all URLs that contain a question mark.  That URL has a question mark and query parameters.

It is appropriate that you have blocked that URL with robots.txt.   It is a site search results page.  Google doesn't want users to click from Google Search only to land on another page of search results.  That is bad user experience.  If you were to unblock that page, Google could penalize your entire site.  See [Matt Cutts: Search results in search results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/)

Google occasionally indexes URLs that are blocked by robots.txt even when it can't crawl them and show snippets from them in the search results.  That is what is happening in this case.   That is usually because:

- The URL is linked prominently from somewhere
- You don't have another crawlable page on your site that is relevant for those keywords

To fix this issue you should:

- Not link to your catalog search anywhere on your own site.  Site search should only be available to users who type into a search box, there should be no direct links with a search already filled in.
- Track down external links to that site search and ask other sites to remove them.  You could suggest they replace them with something more relevant
- Create a crawlable page on your site for those keywords (assuming you have a product that is relevant for them.)